# How to reference the default schema in liquibase preCondition sqlCheck

Tags: sql, insert, schema, liquibase, preconditions

Posting here in case it helps someone.

```
TLDR: ${database.defaultSchemaName} within sqlCheck to access default schema name
```

I wanted my database `changeset` to first check if a certain row is present in the database. If not present, it should execute the `changeset`.

Example:

**myschema.customers**:

| uuid | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Bob | 22 |
| 0002 | Sally | 25 |

What I want: liquibase to check if uuid = 0002 is present in the `myschema.customers` table. If so, run the `changeset`, otherwise skip over it.

Initially I tried this:

```
<changeSet id="00000000000007" author="jhipster">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
            select count(*) from customers WHERE uuid= '0002'
        </sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <insert tableName="customers">
        <column name="uuid" value="0002"></column>
        <column name="name" value="Sally"></column>
        <column name="age" value="25"></column>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Bear in mind that I have set the following configuration for liquibase (4.6.1)

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        default-schema: myschema
```

But it seems precondition sqlcheck was checking `public.customers` and not `myschema.customers`. This would cause an error when uuid 0002 is already present in `myschema.customers`.

---

**SOLUTION**: use `${database.defaultSchemaName}`

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
        select count(*) from ${database.defaultSchemaName}.customers WHERE uuid= '0002'
    </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
```

Comment: Can you clarify: did you have a question or is this an informational post for other SO users?

Comment: Ah @tabbyfoo, I meant it to be an informational post. Wasn't sure if it's better practice post Qn + Ans separately but decided to combine them